# Problem with 3D printer not accepting new print gcodes

Tags: g-code

Ok so I am trying to print a new fusion 360 file that I converted into an STL and then into gcode using cura and I got the gcode loaded onto the SD card and mounted into my Monoprice 3D printer, Maker Select 3D Printer v2, and tried to do a print. Now here is the strange part. When I choose "print file" and then select a gcode to print it takes me back to the main screen and from there the 3D printers screen displays "Printing...0%" for a few seconds. After this it just goes back to displaying "Stepper Disabled." And if it is not stepper disabled it is just a blank screen. I tried to mount and print multiple gcodes just to make sure that it was not the softwares fault and low and behold I was running into the same issue.

Now before using today all of the gcode was printing just fine, however for some reason today it decided to give me this issue.

Comment: Never mind. It turns out that I only needed to reformat the SD card. :D

Comment: Nice, I will to reformat a micro SD that is read some times.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I actually have experienced  similar problems that got away when the SD card was reformatted as well. Maybe this question should be saved for eternity after all! :) Please add the answer to your own question (should be possible within a few hours) so that you can accept the solution and people can vote.

Comment: I rolled the edit back because it was removing information like the printer and slicer...is it really necessary to go this hardcore with edits?  I'm sure everyone could read it the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Determined Solution

Ok so after an hour or so of searching and trying to figure this out, I found that the best to deal with this is by reformating the SD Card once the problem starts.

Now I had to make sure that I made a backup of all the files so that I could recover them once the process was complete.

Also please note that the problem may have been with one of the files on the SD Card so backing up the SD Card and then restoring the files from your place of storage for the SD card may or may not work.

Also, this problem and solution were done on a Monoprice 3D Printer V2 so I am not sure how this would work with any other 3D printer.

Answer (score 5):

As you found out, sometimes the SD cards need reformating.

And if they came with the printer they could be fake (Fake capacity), when you try to upload more than its real capacity they will just corrupt.

My Anet A8 came with an 8GB SD card and it turned out to be 128 mb. With [RMPrepUSB](https://www.rmprepusb.com) you can do a capacity test and format it to the real capacity.